# Windows Service integrate with WCF hosted and send notification to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, windows-services

I am developing an application that will have the following structure:

[image: structure]

I'm new to web development, I chose the ASP.NET MVC to work with Microsoft technologies, I believe that facilitates development.

With this in mind, I would like to know how do I make my WCF service to communicate with the ASP.NET page?

The idea is my hardware send information to page without the page requesting the WCF information. The website would only wait for something to happen without interacting with WCF service.

I conducted some research, but I could not adapt to my need or could not clearly understand.

Comment: Have a look at SignalR to communicate from backend services to web pages. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr